# Urban dictionary API with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api

I've been trying to get the definition of a word from the urban dictionary API

```
 fetch(
`https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define?term=${uSearch}`,
{
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "a9fb0095e3msh7092e19dd0034e9p1261a5jsnb924703f4137",
  },
}
```

This is the result I'm getting:
[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp3pu.png)

How do i get the definition out of the api? I've tried: response.definition and response.body.definition

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch

Comment: Looks like you're getting a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream

Answer (score 1):

`fetch()` returns a Promise which resolves to a Response, so you need to return the type of Response you want from the first `.then()` and then return from it and handle the result in the second `.then()`:

```js
 fetch(
`https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define?term=${uSearch}`,
{
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "a9fb0095e3msh7092e19dd0034e9p1261a5jsnb924703f4137",
  },
})
.then(response => response.json()) // or .text(), or .blob(), etc
.then(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: fwiw, it is possible to use the json api without signing up to anything. Here's an example url `https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=tiago&page=2`. That said, I've not been able to find any documentation for this API (found this thread while looking and would appreciate a link if anyone knows), but there are apps using it that haven't been updated in the past few  years (but still work) so it seems stable.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` returns a `Promise`, and the readable stream should parsed.
This means, that you should have fetch in this way:

```
let returnedData = fetch(url, options).then(function(data){return data.json()})
```

understand that this is an asynchronous line of code. however, the `then` keyword will only run once the fetch call was either resolved or rejected.